# Why Am I able to edit /etc/resolv.conf on a read only file system?

Tags: linux, root-filesystem, readonly

I have an embedded linux environment which has a read only root file system on it.
I am unable to edit files and create new directory in the read only root file system as expected.

However, I see that I am still able to change the contents of file `/etc/resolv.conf`
How is that possible? This actually works out for me. But I was just wondering why am I able to edit it?

Edit1: I am even able to create a write into `/sys/class/pwm/$module_name/export`
Edit 2: So I see that

```
resolv.conf -> /etc/resolv-conf.systemd
```

And

```
resolv-conf.systemd -> ../run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Comment: does the change survive a reboot?

Comment: Run `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` and see how it's a symlink somewhere, possibly `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` or `/usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @jsotola no the change does not survive reboot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I see that I am still able to change the contents of file /etc/resolv.conf How is that possible?

It's either a symbolic link to a tmpfs filesystem mounted e.g. in `/run` or `/var` or you're working with a [virtual COW filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) like UnionFS/aufs/overlayfs/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running bind mounts.
If running RHEL/Fedora, you're using package `readonly-root` which performs bind mounts for any dir/file in `/etc/rwtab` and `/etc/rwtab.d`.
By default, `/etc/resolv.conf` is included in `/etc/rwtab`.

You can check this behavior by running `mount | grep resolv` which should output something like

```
none on /etc/resolv.conf type tmpfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,inode64)
```

You can also have a partition that holds data that should be kept, see `/etc/statetab` and `/etc/statetab.d` folders.